# Cross-reference format in exam class

Tags: cross-referencing, exam

I need to reference a part in a question, but I have the part redefined to include the number of the question as well. How can I make the reference format to show this as well?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\arabic{partno}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\bfseries\thequestion.\thepartno.}
\begin{document}
    \qformat{\textbf{\large{Problem \thequestion}} \hfill \vrule depth 1em width 0pt}
    \begin{questions}
    \question
    The main question.
    \begin{parts}
        \part 
        This is part 1.1. \label{mylabel}
        \part
        This is part 1.1 but it is related to part \ref{mylabel} somehow.
    \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This shows "This is part 1 but it is related to part 1 somehow.", instead of "This is part 1 but it is related to part 1.1 somehow."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LaTeX referencing system uses `\thepartno`, so you have to add the question in `\thepartno` instead of only adding it in `\partlabel`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\thequestion.\arabic{partno}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\bfseries\thepartno.}
\begin{document}
    \qformat{\textbf{\large{Problem \thequestion}} \hfill \vrule depth 1em width 0pt}
    \begin{questions}
    \question
    The main question.
    \begin{parts}
        \part 
        This is part 1.1. \label{mylabel}
        \part
        This is part 1.2 but it is related to part \ref{mylabel} somehow.
    \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Duh, why didn't I think of this. Thanks!

Comment: I would be grateful if you could edit your answer to include how it is done using `cleveref`. Thanks